# How I can define a list of map::iterator and map of list::iterator

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, iterator, std

I need a list of Map::iterator and map of List::iterator. How I can do this:

```
typedef std::list<Map::iterator> List;
typedef std::map<int, List::iterator> Map;
```

Maybe I can use something like forward declaration for iterator?

Comment: Sound like a recursive definition. Are you sure this is the correct solution for your problem? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm sure.
If I use only plain pointer it's not a problem, because I can make forward declaration structure/class. In this case I want to use iterators like plain pointers.

Comment: So, you will have a Map that when given an `Int` will return an `iterator` to a `List`, which holds an `iterator` to a `Map`, which holds and `iterator` to a 'List'... and so on. Maybe your solution is 3 different types?

Comment: One of the possible solutions is to use a type-erasure, make second parameter to be `boost::any`, for example.

Comment: @PazO My code in the question above is a simple example only for illustrate problem.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot can you give code?

Comment: Here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bbf744786a70ea0

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks. I already use similar code. But problem still actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct decl_t {
    typedef std::map<std::string, decl_t> map_t;
    typedef std::list<std::pair<int, typename map_t::iterator>> list_t;

    list_t::iterator it;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    decl_t::map_t map;
    decl_t::list_t list;

    auto list_it = list.emplace(list.end(), 42, decl_t::map_t::iterator());
    const auto pair = std::make_pair(std::string("key"), decl_t{list_it});
    auto result = map.insert(pair);
    assert(result.second);
    auto map_it = result.first;
    list_it->second = map_it;

    std::cout << list_it->second->first << std::endl;
    std::cout << map_it->second.it->first << std::endl;
}
```