# std::map with iterators to std::list from iterators of std::map

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

How should I declare std::list(1) with iterators to std::map, which maps std::string to iterators of std::list (1) ? Is it possible?

```
std::list<std::map<std::string, (1) ???>::iterator>;
std::map<std::string, (1) ???::iterator>;
```

The reason I want this - FIFO queue with ability to fast remove by key.

One possible solution:

```
struct decl_t {
    typedef std::map< std::string, decl_t > map_t;
    typedef std::list< std::pair< int, typename map_t::iterator > > list_t;

    list_t::iterator it;
};
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470987/how-i-can-define-a-list-of-mapiterator-and-map-of-listiterator

Comment: You're getting in trouble because you want to let both containers reference each other. One should contain data, the other the references (via iterators).  If you want to avoid bookkeeping, you might take a look at [boost.multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) or [boost.bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) whichever suits better.

Comment: You might be better off storing a structure that encapsulates both your string and a shared handle of some description that can be stored in your map. The handle can contain a boolean flag `dontExecute` that you can set to `true`. That way, you don't actually remove the element from the FIFO but once it reaches the front you can simply check `theElement.handle->dontExecute` and skip handling if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is ugly, but complete example

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct decl_t {
    typedef std::map<std::string, decl_t> map_t;
    typedef std::list<std::pair<int, typename map_t::iterator>> list_t;

    list_t::iterator it;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    decl_t::map_t map;
    decl_t::list_t list;

    auto list_it = list.emplace(list.end(), 42, decl_t::map_t::iterator());
    const auto pair = std::make_pair(std::string("key"), decl_t{list_it});
    auto result = map.insert(pair);
    assert(result.second);
    auto map_it = result.first;
    list_it->second = map_it;

    std::cout << list_it->second->first << std::endl;
    std::cout << map_it->second.it->first << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of a FIFO with the ability to remove by key, I suggest you use [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), as you have no need for order in the map.

Following that, perhaps you could change your cross-referencing scheme. Use a list of strings, and a map mapping strings to iterators of such a list:

```
#include <unordered_map>                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <list>
#include <string>


using map_t = unordered_map<string, list<string>::iterator>;
using list_t = list<string>;
```

For the direction of finding a key in the map once you have an iterator in the list, you need to perform a redundant hash on the name relative to your full iterator-to-iterator scheme, but it is still *O(1)* (expected). Conversely, your original scheme required logarithmic operations for removal by key, so you're probably still ahead.

To insert a new element, you could do something like this:

```
map_t map;
list_t list;

list.push_back("koko");
auto it = --list.end();
map["koko"] = it;
```

---

**Example**

```
#include <unordered_map>                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <list>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    using map_t = unordered_map<string, list<string>::iterator>;
    using list_t = list<string>;

    map_t map;
    list_t list;

    list.push_back("koko");
    auto it = --list.end();
    map["koko"] = it;
}
```

Comment: @PreferenceBean (formerly LightnessRacesIntoOrbit?), many thanks for the useful edit!

Comment: It might seem trivial, but I originally commented that your opening statement was nonsense because a FIFO _of course_ has a certain ordering. Hadn't realised you were talking about the indexing map specifically. So I disambiguated it :)

Comment: @PreferenceBean and I completely agree with your original comment (and subsequent edit) - at that point in the answer, it was misleading. Many thanks.